# AWS Cloudwatch agent: new log in `collect_list` not being added

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

On a linux EC2 instance, I have modified `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/config.json` and added a new logfile to the `collect_list` object, followed by doing `sudo service amazon-cloudwatch-agent restart` --  however, this does not update the various configs for the agent, and the new logfile isn't being added. What's the trick here to make the agent reload from an updated `config.json`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds themselves in the same situation, to reload the cloudwatch agent config:

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/config.json -s
```